# Search all content fields with "find content" module instead of title

Tags: search

I want to search all fields instead of the title only.

Right now I'm using the "[find content](https://www.drupal.org/project/find_content)" module. Tried to find another one which is similar but am not able to find.

Comment: You can always use Search API module which gives you better customisation options than Core "Search module"

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use the [Administration views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) and edit the view to suit your needs. Edit the view with an exposed search filter.

Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for superior usability.

Features

> Filter all administrative views via AJAX. Perform any kind of
>   bulk/mass operations on items in administrative views. Filter content
>   by title, node type, author, published status, and/or vocabulary.
>   Filter comments by title, author, node title, or published status.
>   Filter users by name, ban/blocked status, or user roles.
>   *Note: If you are upgrading from an older version of Administration views and the default views have been overridden (saved in the
>   database) you could encounter issues or not see any new changes unless
>   you revert these views, so the default in-code views are used. This
>   can be done in the views UI listing or using drush (drush cter
>   views_view --module=admin_views)